# jquery content only showing once

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('nav>li').hide();
    $('ul').hide();
    $('h2').hide();

          $('a.btnDown').click(function () {
          $('body').css('background', 'tomato');
           $('nav>ul li:hidden').each(function(i) {
           //$('nav>h1').fadeOut(300);
            //$('nav>ul').fadeIn(200);
            $('h1').hide();

            $('nav>ul').delay(i*600).fadeIn(200);
            return false;
        });



    }); //closes a.btnDown

     $('nav>li').click(function () {
        $('nav>ul li:visible').each(function(i) { 

            $('h1').show();
            $('nav>li').hide();
            $('ul li').hide();
            //clearTimeout(fadeTimeout);
            $('nav>li').delay(i*600).fadeOut(200);

        }); //closes visible i

        return false;
        }); //closes a.btnDown

    //all the content elements
    var $suls = $('body>aside>ul');
    var $as = $('a.contentDown').click(function () {
                $('h2').show();
                var $smL = $('h2');
                $smL.animate({
                    left: 300})
            //move nav out of way
                var $nav = $('.navBar');
                $nav.css("left", "auto");
                $nav.animate({
                    right:  300})
            //move menu out of way
                var $menu = $('.menu');
                $nav.css("left", "auto");
                $menu.animate({
                    bottom:  300})
        //hide visible content item
        $suls.filter(':visible').hide();
        //display the content item in the same position as the clicked contentDown
        $suls.eq($as.index(this)).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    }); //closes contentDown

    $('a.bck').click(function() {

    var $aAside = $('aside');
    $('aside>ul>li:visible').hide();
    $aAside.animate({
        left: 300
    })
    var $smL = $('h2');
        $smL.animate({
            left: -300})
        //move nav back in way
            var $nav = $('.navBar');
            $nav.animate({
            left: 10
            })
    return false;
    }); //closes bck click

}); //closes .ready()
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPDkg/ is a link to the code I am working on. When you go to menu>part one>back and then click part one again, the content doesn't show up after you already clicked it. Wondering what is causing this, not necessarily the answer, but anything is helpful thank you.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, with perhaps what you think the problem might be? It is frowned upon to just post a bunch of code without explaining it. It makes it a lot more work for people to help you solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the back button was clicked, you were hiding the `li` element. When the navigation elements was clicked, you were showing the `ul` element. As a result, the `li` element would be hidden, yet you were toggling between the visibility of the `ul`; thus nothing would ever be displayed.

To solve this, simply hide the parent `ul` as opposed to the `li` when the back button is clicked.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpL28/)

Change this:

```
$('aside>ul>li:visible').hide();
$aAside.animate({
    left: 300
})
```

To this:

```
$('aside>ul:visible').hide();
$aAside.animate({
    left: 300
})
```